# Getting text input without swing in Java

Tags: java, swing, input, jtextfield

Hi I'm making a game in Java that randomly generates 100 numbers, and then
ask the user to memorize as many as then can and then try to recall as many as they can. My game uses a JPanel and a Graphics g object to do all the drawing. How do I "draw" a JTextfield or get one to work on a jpanel?

Comment: Why not just use a `JTextField` and simply add it to a container of your choice?  Maybe you should have a look at [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a ActionListener to JTextField and then add that JTextField to JPanel. Now add this JPanel to JFrame using `this.add(jpnel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);` 
Create a new JPanel class Board where you draw things. Add that JPanel to JFrame as, `this.add(new Board(), BorderLayout.CENTER);`. 
Here I coded one example for you. Now you should have an idea how to do that...

**Board class**

```
    public class Board extends JPanel {

    int[] numbers = {3, 25, 5, 6, 60, 100};
    int index = 0;
    static String num;
    boolean once = true;
    FontMetrics fm;

    Board() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        setBackground(Color.decode("#ffde00"));
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (index < 6) {
            num = numbers[index] + "";
        } else {
            num = "Game Ended.";
            Window.ans.setEditable(false);
        }
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 50));
        if(once){
            fm = g2.getFontMetrics();
            once = false;
        }
        int x = ((getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(num)) / 2);
        int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
        g2.drawString(num + "", x, y);
        index++;
    }

}
```

**Window class**

```
    public class Window extends JFrame {

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Enter the number if you have seen it before, Else empty.");
    JLabel res = new JLabel("....");
    static JTextField ans = new JTextField(10);
    Board board = new Board();

    public Window() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout(8, 8));
        p.add(lbl, BorderLayout.WEST);
        ans.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (ans.getText().equals(Board.num)) {
                    res.setText("Good");
                } else {
                    res.setText("Bad");
                }
                ans.setText("");
                board.repaint();
            }

        });
        p.add(ans, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p.add(res, BorderLayout.EAST);
        p.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        this.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setResizable(false);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Window();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you add a `KeyListener` to a `JTextField` ? That is what a `DocumentListener` is for. Besides, if you only listen for ENTER, you might as well add an `ActionListener` to the `JTextField`, which is triggered each time ENTER is pressed.

Comment: He could simply use jtf.getText();

Comment: @CodeRunner with in the textfield? Oh in that case I understand.

Comment: I generate all the random numbers into an array and then draw them to the screen with g.drawString(); The g.drawString methods are in the random number class, and then I have  a seperate class that is supposed to get the input. So you're saying I just go to the GamePanel class (contains main game loop and JPanel stuff) and add the jtexfield there which can use a static boolean from the input class to determine whether to draw or not?

Comment: It doesn't work. Adding the JTextField to the JPanel does not work because it's immediately covered by images drawn by the Graphics g object.